# Python system log file

Tags: python, exception, logging

I have a script that has been crashing (seemingly) unpredictably. I can't work out how to reproduce it.

Does Python keep a global system log file, so I can go back and look at what exception precipitated the exit? If so, where can it be found on Windows? I'd like to be able to see a traceback too if possible.

**edit**: I know I *could* put the whole script inside a `try...except` block, but I don't know how long I'll be running it before it crashes again. I'd like to be able to at least gain some cursory information about crashes that have already happened, even if that information is just the type of exception that caused the crash. That way I can try to reproduce the bug more reliably.

I suspect the crash been caused by failed communication with external devices (perhaps something as simple a loose cable). These sorts of failure are essentially random and difficult to reproduce, so I'd like to know if it was a communication error or a genuine code bug.

Comment: See "post-mortem" debugging in the python docs.

Comment: What script is this that you're trying to run? Could you post a small snippet where you think the problem occurs?

Comment: It looks like the post-mortem debugger in pdb only works on the last crash, and within the same instance of the interpreter. I'd like to be able to look at a list of all the times Python has crashed in (say) the last 24 hours and see what went wrong. Is this possible?

Comment: The problem is that I'm not sure where the problem occurs. The script talks to several external devices, and I suspect one of them is the culprit. If I had a list of recent exceptions I'd be able to start work on finding out what the issue actually is.

Comment: @poorsod Maybe if you have file-based logging (with timestamps, instance identifiers, python versions) and tracebacks in your script, you could refer the log file and pinpoint the problem. Since it appears to happen only sometimes, you sure you use the right python version on all instances of the interpreter?

Comment: @SagarHatekar I hadn't implemented `logging` in my script at the time of the crash (my fault, I know...), which is why I'm trying to find a global Python system log.

Comment: @poorsod While we try to find a global system log, it might also help to implement logging in key code snippets. Chances are, if it happened in the past - it may happen again. Happy Debugging :)

Comment: @SagarHatekar way ahead of you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the information about **exception** you can use this code.

```
try:
    #do some stuff
    1/0 #stuff that generated the exception
except Exception as ex:
    print ex
    raw_input()
```

For debugging it properly there is a tool [winpdb](http://winpdb.org/). There is a very good tutorial available for it to learn debugging using it [debugging tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/winpdb/wiki/DebuggingTutorial)

Comment: I'm perfectly familiar with `try...except` and debugging techniques. I would like to be able to go back to an instance that crashed half an hour ago and find out what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Can you "catch" the `exception`? If yes, then you can use `traceback` to print the stacktrace and pinpoint where the problem occurs.

Then you can debug the module in question (even if it's part of the python lib, it will be in plain readable form) using Eclipse.

```
import traceback
...
...

try:
    <your script>
except Exception as runtime_ex:
    print runtime_ex, traceback.format_exc()
```